# Node Express third party api call from the backend server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, axios

I'm building a simple website that calls a third party api and displays the information. I want to do all my api calls in the backend because I read that it is a little bit more secure. I have a component that takes in a submitted search term, sends it to the server for the server to call the api using the search term but I'm having trouble with exactly how to do that.
This is what I have on my server.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const axios = require('axios')
    const app = express();
    const port = 8000
    const cors = require("cors");

    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    app.use(cors())

    app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body)
        const {search} = req.body
        axios.get(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search=${search}`)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data.data)
                res.send(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    })

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

And this is the useEffect that calls the server in my component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/search`, {
            search: `${props.search}`
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
   }, [])
```

Comment: Other than that you're POST'ing at the client but then GET'ing on the server, this looks fine, what's the actual problem you're having? Or perhaps I should ask: are you just making the client search something? because if so, it will be talking to your server, not "to axios", and you should be able to just use the Fetch API instead of using axios calls.

Comment: when I run the post request from my component in postman it says it doesnt get a response so it sounds like its not retrieving the data from the api

Comment: then it sounds like you want that post to just be a regular old POST request to your server, not an "axios API call", so change that to a [fetch call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and you should be good to go.